# How to plot multiple lines within pandas / matplotlib for

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have data of the following structure:

```
0  0 0 0 1 0 1 4 8 0 9
1  0 1 4 2 3 4 5 1 2 4
2  1 4 2 9 4 5 2 4 5 6
```

(this continues for 100 rows and has 48 columns in total)

The first column a time interval between 0 and 100, each next column shows the number of contacts between two interacting particles. E.g. column 5 shows that at t=0, 1 contact occurs, at t=1, 2 contacts etc.
I'd like to represent the number of contacts over time for each particle in a 3D line plot.
I thought to have time (column 0) on the x-axis, number of contacts on the z-axis and the respective particle number (column 1 to n) on the y-axis.
I am relatively new to python and saw that matplotlib / pandas offers some possibilities to input data from table files and plot in 3D. So here's what I've done so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
data=pd.read_table(path, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
x_data=data.iloc[0:100, 0:1]
z_data=data.iloc[0:100, 1:]
y_data=np.arange(1, 47, 1)
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot(x_data, y_data, z_data)
plt.show()
```

The x_data, y_data and z_data assignments have the exact data that I want them to have (checked with, e.g.print(z_data)). But the final part of the script regarding the plotting failes with the following error:
ValueError: input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis remapping

Am I splicing the input data wrongly? Or is the plot function not to be used like that for 3D visualisation? I saw already that it takes a meshgrid for two values and then a function for the third - however, I am not aware of how to express my data in such a way.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: why you want a 3D plot? what about a simple 2D plot with different colors for each column? I doubt that it will be easier to understand a 3D plot

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion! The issue with different colors is that there are 47 different lines to plot with partially overlapping datapoints. I think that this will be quite unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do you 3D plot, note sure about the readability.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#data= here your code to read data

x_data=data.iloc[:,0].to_numpy()
n = len(data)
ax =  plt.figure().add_subplot(projection="3d")
for i, col in enumerate(data.columns[1:],1):
    ax.plot(x_data, [i]*n, data[col].to_numpy())
plt.show()
```